# Get timezone abbreviation from timezone name

Tags: javascript, timezone, locale

How can we find time zone abbreviation from time zone name. Is there any library which we can use to get it.

e.g.:
Input- America/Los_Angeles
Output- PDT

I tried using

```
usertimezone = America/Los_Angeles
print(new Date().toLocaleTimeString('en-us',{timeZone: usertimezone, timeZoneName:'short'}).split(' ')[2]);

output- PDT
```

But we need to provide locale. For different marketplaces locale would be different. If locale is incorrect then it provides answer based on GMT+offset.

E.g. while using time zone as "Asia/Calcutta" output is GMT+5:30. But with locale 'en-in' output is IST

Is it possible to do with plain JavaScript or a framework or library?

Comment: Java is neither a framework, nor related to JavaScript. It a separate programming language.

Comment: Note: the two concepts are really different (but usually confused in one). One it is time zone, and the other time offset. Los Angeles may have different time offset (standard time, summer time), but also it may change the time offset (maybe not for Los Angeles, but for cities near the timezone border (E.g. switched from Mountain to Pacific). So, just print the timezone from a date (time format strings). And yes, you need a precise date.